# Is It Okay To Use JAXX?

Tags: java, css, swing

I have noticed that [JAXX framework](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html) allows Java Swing to be styled using CSS, this is a functionality that I have always wanted. However, JAXX seems to be pretty old so I am not sure whether it would work with modern versions of Java (and CSS)?

Comment: It seems that [somebody else](http://www.nuiton.org/projects/show/jaxx) took over the project after the original developer abandoned it. The current release at this time is from May 2011, so it's fairly recent.

Comment: Yes we are doing the job. :)

Comment: Are there any documentation in english? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We continue the developement of the JAXX project (See http://jaxx.nuiton.org/v/2.24/).

We use for many clients this project under any java version (from 1.4 to 1.8).